# i cant use local database file in my project in c#

Tags: c#, sql

when I was trying to use **local database** file in my project in **c#** this *error* was shown:

> the database cannot show because it is version 904.this server support
>   version and earlier 852.

I use VS 2019 and SQL 2019.
I cant understand why show this error when I create my tables in SQL 2019.

Comment: Is the mdf file attached to a server?  The server owns the file.  LocalDb is directly connecting to the mdf file.  If attached to a database you must connect directly to the server instead of MDF.  So remove the Attach from the connection string.  Are you using Trusted_Connection=Yes;"Trusted_Connection=Yes;" or "Username/Password".  When you connect using SQL Server Management Studio does the login say Window Credential?  Then use Trusted_Connection=Yes;

Comment: MDF file isn't attached to any server and I use Trusted_Connection=Yes;is there any way to build setup file ?i cant use VS inetaler.

Comment: Trusted Connection implies the database is attached to the database.  If it is not connected then do not use Trusted Connection.  Is database on local machine or remote machine?  If file is one a remote machine I usually test that I can access the file by opening a File Explorer and see if I can locate the file in the explorer.  If I can't see the file in the explorer than I know there is an issue accessing the file.

Comment: Mdf file is on local.I want make exe file in c#.I can open database and make change when I use sql server connection but when I want open mdf file in VS this error show.I try 2020 sql server but it's not work.

Comment: Database is attached to SSMS so you do not use the MDF file in the connection string.  So remove from connection string ATTACH DABASE.  Then using SSMS there is a login window which has the server name (usually the PC but can be ..) / instance.  Use the exactly what is in the login window in the connection string.  The login window should have Window Credential so the connection string will have Trusted_Connection=Yes;